# Publish an Asp.Net Web Api Self-hosted console application as Azure Webjob

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API Self-host console application and I want to publish it as a Azure Webjob service. Is it possible, is it advisable?.
I'm using Topshelf to install it as a windows service on my local server.
I haven't a web application only the console application.

Answer (score 2):

In a Webjob, no. See Azure App Service sandbox limitations [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening) - assuming you need to listen for inbound requests on a socket.

Installing stuff (think .msi or writing to registry) is also not supported.

Look at Cloud Services (Worker Role), Service Fabric or IaaS VMs.
They're all options.

**EDIT** (sometime in 2017):

Now there's even more option: Docker containers in Azure App Service Linux, Azure Container Service (DC/OS, Swarm or Kubernetes as orchestrator) or Azure Container Instance.